# Bound mismatch: The type A is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Entity> of the type TestService<T>

Tags: java, generics

Im getting this exception when compiling MyService.
What is the issue in the generics definition here?

```
public interface Entity extends Serializable{

    public <T extends Serializable> T getId();

}

public  class A  implements Entity {
... some code
}



public abstract class TestService<T extends Entity> implements Serializable {
...some code
}

public class MyService extends TestService<A> {
...some code
}
```

Comment: Seems fine here: http://ideone.com/RLmhBj

Comment: Also works for me... what version of JVM are you using??

Comment: That's weird... I'm using the same jdk... however, I try your code compiling with the eclipse IDE... what are you using to compile: command line? maven?

Comment: @CarlitosWay thanks for trying out..The confusion caused with two duplicate classes in two different packages.

Answer (score 0):

The error simply tells that the type parameter **T** you are using here `public abstract class TestService<T extends Entity> implements Serializable {`  is a bound parameter extending `Entity`.

Whereas, here `public class MyService extends TestService<A> {`, you are specifying an unbound parameter **A**.

I am not sure whether it has to do anything with the Java version 5 onwards, you can refer this [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)